# Make loaded elements jQuery objects

Tags: jquery, ajax

As I've discovered with Ajax in jQuery, loaded elements are not jQuery objects. What's the best way to 'rescan' the document to make elements loaded with Ajax jQuery objects?

In the code below `jq('.storyBlock button').click(function()` and the other functions do not fire on the loaded Ajax html. How best to change this code so they will fire?

```
var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

jq(document).ready(function() {
    // Disable buttons after clicking
    jq('.storyBlock button').click(function() {
        jq(this).addClass('selected');
        jq(this).parent().addClass('disabled');
        jq(this).parent().find('button').attr('disabled', true);
    });
    // Event Handler
    jq('.storyBlock button').click(function() {
        // Find link
        var getID = jq(this).data('link');
        console.log(getID + '.html');

        // Load file and insert after last story
        jq.ajax(getID + '.html').done(function(html) {
        jq('#stories > div:last-child').after(html);
        if ( (getID) != 'start' ) {
            jq('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jq('#' + getID).offset().top },'slow');
        } else {
            jq('.storyBlock').remove();
            jq('#stories > div' ).load( "start.html" );
            jq('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: jq('#start').offset().top },'slow');
        }
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)!!!

Comment: @ArunPJohny is correct. If you're dynamically adding elements to the DOM you will need to use event delegation

Comment: @ArunPJohny I don't think it's useful to yell "event delegation!!!" at the OP and/or downvote this question even if the problem concerns a fundamental concept of the technology involved.

Comment: @Filburt I didn't downvote... but the links provided will help solve the problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. I'm still not sure how this function can be applied to my code above to make it work. Something like this: `$(document).on( load, function(){} );` ?

Comment: you need to change the event registration to `jq(document).on('click', '.storyBlock button', function() {..})`

Comment: @ArunPJohny - Ah, by adding that and removing the click function inside, it now behaves as expected. This function is very useful to know. Thanks. If you want to add that as the answer I will mark as correct - thank you.

Comment: @PaulRedmond sure will do... (since there are no answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) since you need to handler dynamic elements

So convert your event handlers to

```
jq(document).on('click', '.storyBlock button', function() {
})
```